# How to convert enumrate pyspark code into scala code

Tags: scala, pyspark, enumerate

Below is the pyspark code for matrix multiplication. I need same code logic in  scala for matrix multiplication as this logic is good for large volume dataset.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

df = spark.sql("select * from tablename")

colDFs = []
for c2 in df.columns:
    colDFs.append( df.select( [ F.sum(df[c1]*df[c2]).alias("op_{0}".format(i)) for i,c1 in enumerate(df.columns) ] ) )

mtx = reduce(lambda a,b: a.select(a.columns).union(b.select(a.columns)), colDFs )
mtx.show()
```

Comment: Requests to write code to spec are off-topic for this site. Perhaps, you'd have better luck on freelancer.com, taskrabbit etc. ... Otherwise, you might want to try implementing this yourself and posting again here if you run into a specific problem or have a specific question you cannot find an answer to on your own.

Answer (score 0):

for enumerate you can use zipWithIndex as in `df.columns.zipWithIndex`

I didn't test it but overall code should be something like

```
val colsDf=df.columns.flatMap{ case c => 
  df.columns.zipWithIndex.map{ case (c2,i) => 
    df.select(sum(col(c)*col(c2).alias(s"op_$i")))
  }
}
colsDf.reduce((a,b)=>a.select(a.columns.map(col):_*).union(b.select(b.columns.map(col):_*)))
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do and it is out of scope for the original question. you should probably start a new question with more details

Comment: Thanks Arnon!!! this code is working but output data is getting in single column only.How we can get in matrix format.

Comment: example..my input matrix is 41 * 41 and after matrix multiplication results should be in 41 * 41 matrix. but i am getting output data in single column having 1681 rows which is (41 *41 =1681)

Comment: did you try to take a look at spark linarg classes https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/Matrix.html

Comment: yes have tried but not getting data in matrix.

Comment: regarding slowness you need to cache the df to memory/disk otherwise it re-read the DF on each query.  anyway if thats 41 by 41 matrix hardly seems a use-case for spark

Comment: 41 by 41 its not fixed, this will change based on input upto 160 by 160. Now only challenge is that getting output data in single column instead in matrix format.Output should be in 41 by 41 matrix but getting all (41 *41 =1681) rows in single column only.

Comment: when you construct the df you need to do withColumn to construct the columns and union to construct rows

Comment: still 161x161 is a small problem that is not a good fit for spark

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I am new to Scala Language so if possible can you please update construct logic in existing scala code.

Comment: Have started new question for same.Please check and update 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660795/getting-output-data-in-single-column-instead-of-matrix-in-scala