# How to Get all header name in new single column in scala/pyspark/sql

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, pyspark

I need all header columns name in new single column in any language like sql/pyspark/scala.First choice would be in Pyspark.
I am trying below matrix multiplication code.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

df = spark.sql("select * from tablename")

colDFs = []
for c2 in df.columns:
    colDFs.append( df.select( [ F.sum(df[c1]*df[c2]).alias(c1.format(i)) for i,c1 in enumerate(df.columns) ] ) )

mtx = reduce(lambda a,b: a.select(a.columns).union(b.select(a.columns)), colDFs )
```

with this code i am getting data in below format.but i want one new column with all header name.
Eg. current output data be like:

| battery | bulbs | tires | seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

Expected Output be like

| **Row1** | battery | bulbs | tires | seats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **battery** | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| **bulbs** | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| **tires** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| **seats** | 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 |

Number of columns are not fixed in this case.if we have 20 columns then in Row1 will get same 20 columns.

Comment: Can you share any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: ``` from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from functools import reduce

df = spark.sql("select * from tablename")

colDFs = []
for c2 in df.columns:
    colDFs.append( df.select( [ F.sum(df[c1]*df[c2]).alias(c1.format(i)) for i,c1 in enumerate(df.columns) ] ) )

mtx = reduce(lambda a,b: a.select(a.columns).union(b.select(a.columns)), colDFs ) ```

Comment: i am trying this code..in final output i want one new column with all header column name

Comment: Please add your code to your question, this will help anyone viewing your Question to see your code easily and clearly.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking. Finally, please make sure your code is formatted :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. If there are more columns than rows, how will this work? What is the final goal of this code? I think if I understood this I could be of better help.

Comment: this is the matrix multiplication code..so no of columns and no of rows will be same.If we have 40 by 40 matrix then will have 40 headers column name and same 40 header columns will be appear in new single columns.

Comment: have updated the question with some rea ltime example..it will be more clarify about my requirement.

Comment: Can you post the sample of the `tablename`?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you..I have put the input and expected output. We can consider any kind of data.I need all header column name in new single column.